# Iteration of Object of arrays of objects Angular4

Tags: html, angular

I need to iterate Object of array of objects in anchor tag. Following is the format of my code

`{"1":{"uri":"test1","name":"test1","icon":"http:\/\/dummyurl\/images\/icons\/test1-icon.png","application_id":1},"2":{"uri":"test2","name":"test2","icon":"http:\/\/dummyurl\/images\/icons\/test2-icon.png","application_id":2},"3":{"uri":"test3","name":"test3","icon":"http:\/\/dummyurl\/images\/icons\/test3-icon.png","application_id":3},"4":{"uri":"test4","name":"test4","icon":"http:\/\/dummyurl\/images\/icons\/test4-icon.gif","application_id":4},"5":{"uri":"test5","name":"test5","icon":"http:\/\/dummyurl\/images\/icons\/test5-icon.png","application_id":5}}`

.ts file

```
this.applicationService.getApplication(id)
    .subscribe(applications => {
    this.applications = applications.response;});
```

html

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" NgForOf=" let obj of applications">
    {{obj.name}} </a>
```

I am stuck in this from last 3-4 hours. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take the time to format your code and question correctly before posting. Also, you have not explained what is not working with the code you posted or what you did to solve it or what your exact confusion is.

Comment: The keys are consecutive numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through them using `Object.keys(apps)`

```
this.applicationService.getApplication(id)
  .map(result => result.response)
  .subscribe(apps=> {
    this.applications = Object.keys(apps).map(k => apps[k])
   });
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let app of applications">{{app | json}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @KId. You not only saved my time. You saved me also :) I was looking for this quick and short answer.